# VS code refactoring not working for JS inside remote container

Tags: javascript, docker, visual-studio-code

I'm developing code that is inside a running docker container and I'm opening this container via the VS code "Attach Visual Studio Code" (local machine).

I'm experiencing a problem that refactoring variables names (F2) is not working for javascript exclusively inside a container. It works fine with python inside container. It works fine outside the container with javascript.

F2 will refactor variables with python inside containers.
F2 will refactor variables with javascript outside of a containers.

F2 gives me only the option to "surround with" inside a docker container without the possibility to rename the variable in javascript.

Container image runnining: PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)"

Output from troubleshoot your keybindings

```
2023-11-14 16:51:35.456 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Soft dispatching keyboard event
    2023-11-14 16:51:35.457 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Resolving [F2]
    2023-11-14 16:51:35.466 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ From 1 keybinding entries, no when clauses matched the context.
    2023-11-14 16:51:35.466 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [], code: F2, keyCode: 113, key: F2
    2023-11-14 16:51:35.466 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [], code: F2, keyCode: 60 ('F2')
    2023-11-14 16:51:35.467 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Resolving [F2]
    2023-11-14 16:51:35.467 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ From 1 keybinding entries, no when clauses matched the context.
```

What I'm observing is that the code actions widget appears, [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRoFZ.png), but I expect the rename widget to appear instead.

Updated VSCode devtools:
When I try to follow the steps in the comment, I get the following results when trying to Inspect Context Keys (inside container):

```
temp1.editorHasRenameProvider
false
temp1.editorTextFocus
true
temp1.editorReadonly
false
```

[vs_code debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBODq.png)

Outside the container, for the same varible:

```
temp1.editorHasRenameProvider
true
```

Comment: What's of interest is the part of the output that says "_no when clauses matched the context_". Check your keybindings. You should see "F2" bound by default with a when clause like `editorHasRenameProvider && editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly`. Now what's left is to figure out which context keys aren't matching and why. In the VS Code [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette), run `Developer: Toggle Developer Tools`, and then in the command palette, run `Developer: Inspect Context Keys` and then click the variable that you want to rename.

Comment: You should see a JS object printed to he devtools console. Right click it and select "Store object as global variable". Then, in that devtools console, type `temp1.editorHasRenameProvider` and check what you see (you want to see "true"). Do the same for `temp1.editorTextFocus` (you want to see "true") and `temp1.editorReadonly` (you want to see "false"). Depending on what you see, either you're just doing something wrong, or it's a problem (possibly due to the container environment), and a bug ticket might be in order.

Comment: okay... hm. there's an off-chance that it could be a static analysis limitation for the code. please provide a [mre]. I doubt it if it works outside the container, but it's better to provide info so I can try it myself.